# Automake failing to compile anything

Tags: compiling, 19.10, mint, autoconf, automake

I've tried to compile programs, including neofetch, cmatrix, browsh, and a few others all to the same effect.

I run:

`git clone repo` Works fine
`cd repo name` Works fine
`./autogen.sh` Works fine
`./configure` Always comes out as something like this:

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of cc... gcc3
checking for c++... c++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether c++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of c++... gcc3
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for protoc... no
configure: error: cannot find protoc, the Protocol Buffers compiler
```

Specifically the last 2 lines are always the same, and then from there `make` and `make install` fail due to there being no file:

`make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`

I've tested on both Ubuntu 19.10 and Linux Mint 19.3

Am I missing a tool or package of some kind?

Comment: Why not: `sudo apt install neofetch`?

Comment: The `protoc` binary is provided by package `protobuf-compiler` and the development package (should it also be required) is `libprotobuf-dev`

Comment: @chili555 Because that version hasn't been updated in several years and I'm trying to get a feature in the latest release, same thing with cmatrix.

Comment: @steeldriver After installing protobuf-compiler, ./autogen.sh still works fine, however ./configure now produces this result: https://pastebin.com/PxQbe9Mk

Comment: @UltraGamer there's really no magic bullet here - every piece of software has prerequisites and you just have to keep picking them off until it successfully configures. For the `zlib` dependency you almost certainly need the `zlib1g-dev` package. *Sometimes* there's a README or INSTALL file that lists the dependencies - other times, it's just trial and error.

Comment: @steeldriver Ok, When I do run into a required dependency such as this next one `configure: error: OpenSSL crypto library not found` where do I find more info about it and how to install it?

Comment: Hmm... my guess is `libssl-dev`

Comment: Thank you, I've now gotten it to compile successfully. Where can I find more about these other dependencies in the future?